# The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated の警告を消したい

Tags: swift4

[image: swift3fからswift4]

swift3からswift4へのマイグレーションの際に、@objcに関するwarningが出たのでBuild
Setting設定のSwift3 @objc Inference の項目をfortune(プロジェクト名),fortuneTests,fortuneUITestsすべてDefaultにかえたのですがfortuneTestと
fortuneUITestの部分の警告が消えません。
どの様にすればこの警告は消せるのでしょうか？
初歩的な質問ですみませんがどなたかご教授していただければ幸いです。

Hikaru na さんこんばんは
警告の内容は

> The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "fortuneUITests" target.

です。お願いします。

Comment: warningの内容を教えて下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/109972